# CloudFunctionsで、プライベートIPを持つMySQLへ接続文字列を利用して接続する方法

Tags: python3, mysql, google-cloud-platform

GoogleCloudPlatformのCloudFunctionsで、
プライベートIPを持つMySQLへ接続文字列を利用して接続する方法を教えてください。

サーバーレスVPCアクセスコネクタを設定することで、
プライベートIPアドレスを指定すれば接続できたのですが、

```
integral-melody-409407:asia-northeast1:mysql
```

のような接続文字列で接続することはできないのでしょうか。
接続文字列で試したところ、以下のエラーが発生します。

```
Error connecting to MySQL Platform: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '/cloudsql/integral-melody-409407:asia-northeast1:mysql' (-2)
```

（プライベートIDアドレスは、変わると思っているので、変らない接続文字列を指定したいです。）

プライベートIPを指定して動作したコード
main.py

```
import functions_framework

import mysql.connector
import os


@functions_framework.http
def mysql_connect(request):
    # 環境変数からデータベースの接続情報を取得
    # db_host = 'integral-melody-409407:asia-northeast1:mysql'  # ←接続できず。
    # db_host = '/cloudsql/integral-melody-409407:asia-northeast1:mysql'  # ←接続できず。
    db_host = '10.51.64.3'  # ←接続できた。
    db_user = 'root'
    db_password = 'root'
    db_name = 'orcas'

    connection = None
    # データベースに接続
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=db_host,
            user=db_user,
            password=db_password,
            database=db_name
        )

        # ここにデータベース操作のコードを記述
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM サンプル;')
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        # 結果を表示（または他の操作）
        result_list = []
        for row in results:
            print(row)
            result_list.append(str(row))

        cursor.close()

    except mysql.connector.Error as exception:
        message = f'Error connecting to MySQL Platform: {exception}'
        print(message)
        return message

    finally:
        if connection:
            if connection.is_connected():
                connection.close()

    # return 'Function executed successfully.'
    return ' / '.join(result_list)
```

requirements.txt

```
functions-framework==3.*
mysql-connector-python
```